# How can I find the percentage of balance?

Tags: logic

I'm developing a game. Assume I have 5 kids. Every kid has different amount of chocolates. Assume each of them has:

- KID 1 has 5 chocolates
- KID 2 has 10 chocolates
- KID 3 has 5 chocolates
- KID 4 has 2 chocolates
- KID 5 has 1 chocolates

What I want is to find the percentage of balance of chocolates. Like if they all have equal amount of chocolates the percentage will be 100%. Yeah, this percentage is a score of the game.

Do you have any logic to find this out? Please help.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to define "percentage of balance", but a reasonable method is:

1. Calculate $\mu$, the average number of chocolates per kid, i.e. the quota.  For the example given, $\mu=(5+10+5+2+1)/5=4.6$.
2. Calculate $s$, the summed square difference of each value from $\mu$.  For the example given, $s=(5-4.6)^2+(10-4.6)^2+(5-4.6)^2+(2-4.6)^2+(1-4.6)^2=49.2$.
3. Calculate $t$, the maximum possible value for $s$.  This would be if all the chocolates were with one kid.  Here $t=(23-4.6)^2+4(0-4.6)^2=423.2$.
4. Finally, rescale from $[0,t]$ to $[100,0]$ via $$f(s)=100\left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)$$
   For the example given, $f(s)\approx 88.4$ percent of balance.

Comment: sorry but, is 4 in t=(23−4.6)2+4(0−4.6)2=423.2. from (kids total - 1)?

Comment: Yes; it is my lazy way of writing $(23-4.6)^2+(0-4.6)^2+(0-4.6)^2+(0-4.6)^2+(0-4.6)^2$.

Comment: Hello, It's been 4 years and I come back to this question because coincidentally I need the formula for my research paper. Can you provide any source for the answer you gave? Thank you @vadim123